# Handling schema change in javers auditing

Tags: java, auditing, javers

I have my java class which consists of Map<String, String>. I am using javers sql repository for storing my auditing data. I recently changed schema of my property to Map<String, List<String>>. Now I am getting following exception on commits of the domain. Schema changes can't be avoided.  How can this exception be handled?

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson$1.deserialize(Gson.java:129) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateDeserializer.decodePropertyValue(CdoSnapshotStateDeserializer.java:48) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateDeserializer.deserialize(CdoSnapshotStateDeserializer.java:39) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.deserializeSnapshotState(CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.java:72) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.fromJson(CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.java:58) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.fromJson(CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter.java:21) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.JsonConverterBuilder$2.deserialize(JsonConverterBuilder.java:133) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.JsonConverter.fromJson(JsonConverter.java:75) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.json.JsonConverter.fromSerializedSnapshot(JsonConverter.java:79) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.repository.sql.finders.CdoSnapshotFinder.fetchCdoSnapshots(CdoSnapshotFinder.java:104) ~[javers-persistence-sql-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.repository.sql.finders.CdoSnapshotFinder.getLatest(CdoSnapshotFinder.java:58) ~[javers-persistence-sql-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.getLatest(JaversSqlRepository.java:46) ~[javers-persistence-sql-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository.getLatest(JaversExtendedRepository.java:87) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.snapshot.GraphShadowFactory.createLatestShadow(GraphShadowFactory.java:32) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.snapshot.GraphSnapshotFacade.createLatestShadow(GraphSnapshotFacade.java:22) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.create(CommitFactory.java:68) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:78) ~[javers-core-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:65) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy469.commit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.OnSaveAuditChangeHandler.handle(OnSaveAuditChangeHandler.java:18) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.applyVersionChange(JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:82) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.applyVersionChanges(JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:77) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.onVersionEvent(JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:59) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.springdata.JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.onSaveExecuted(JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:47) ~[javers-spring-2.8.2.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:611) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:53) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy303.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.BuyerQuoteService.saveAndIndexBuyerQuote(BuyerQuoteService.java:2750) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.BuyerQuoteService.saveAndIndexBuyerQuote(BuyerQuoteService.java:2722) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.BuyerQuoteService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6af0d343.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.BuyerQuoteService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ebbf1160.saveAndIndexBuyerQuote(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.AdminBuyerQuoteServiceV2.bulkUpdateRFQItems(AdminBuyerQuoteServiceV2.java:308) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.AdminBuyerQuoteServiceV2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$29871482.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.ofb.core.aspects.BuyerQuoteAuditAspect.auditBuyerQuoteSave(BuyerQuoteAuditAspect.java:74) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.ofb.core.aspects.Lockable.lockTheWayYouWant(Lockable.java:56) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.ofb.core.rfq.service.AdminBuyerQuoteServiceV2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$27ed0ca5.bulkUpdateRFQItems(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.web.controller.admin.AdminBuyerQuoteV2Controller.updateRFQItems(AdminBuyerQuoteV2Controller.java:187) ~[classes/:?]
at com.ofb.web.controller.admin.AdminBuyerQuoteV2Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81afad49.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.ofb.web.controller.admin.AdminBuyerQuoteV2Controller$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bce1aa1d.updateRFQItems(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at com.ofb.commons.config.web.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:26) [classes/:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_112]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.expect(JsonTreeReader.java:139) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.beginArray(JsonTreeReader.java:58) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814) ~[gson-2.4.jar:?]
... 171 more
```

Comment: Why you are posting the same question on two sites, I mean here and on github? https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/511 Are you expecting two different answers?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, JaVers doesn't handle property type changes. I suggest manual data migration. Try to update property values in already persisted snapshots to the new type.

Comment: Manual data migration will be cumbersome task as there could be many snapshots. Also in future also property type changes may happen. Is there is any other better way to handle this situation?

Comment: yes, implementing this feature https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/511